# Estimates of some function of a parameter (MCMC)

Tags: bayesian, estimation, markov-chain-montecarlo, transform

Let's say I have some MCMC framework whereby I am estimating two parameters

$$(\log\alpha,\log\beta)$$

The reason for the $\log$ functions is so that the implementation of the joint prior distribution on both these parameters is easier.

Let's say I run my MCMC and have two chains of estimates, one for each of these parameters. Overall, my goal was to obtain estimates for $(\alpha,\beta)$. So does it suffice to take both these chains and apply $(e^{\log\alpha_{i}},e^{\log\beta_{i}})$, $\forall i$.

I was going to take the expectation of these posterior chains and get the MMSE estimators.

I'm fairly sure I can't do the above but was looking for some confirmation of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, you can take the transformation of MCMC outputs:** Presumably your initial MCMC work has given you a *joint* chain of values $(\log \alpha_i, \log \beta_i)$ for all $i = 1,2, ..., N$.  Discarding burn-in values and taking large $N$ gives you a set of points generated from the joint posterior for those parameters.  Applying the transformation of values directly to get $(\alpha_i, \beta_i)$ gives you a set of points generated from the joint posterior for those latter parameters.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of any references that might have some similar application of the above transforming?

Comment: It is a consequence of the standard rules for distributions of transformations of random variables.  I suspect that most introductory books and papers on MCMC would discuss it explicitly, but I don't have a specific reference.

Comment: Does the same logic apply if the chain is $(\log\alpha,\beta)$ and I'm only interested in estimates of $(\alpha,\beta)$? Can I take the transform of the single variable $\log\alpha$ alone?

Comment: Yep, same deal.