# Change of variables in MCMC posterior

Tags: probability, random-variable, density-function, markov-chain-montecarlo

I have a question similar to this previously asked [stackexchange question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/335733/estimates-of-some-function-of-a-parameter-mcmc). However, instead of the **expectation value** after a change of variables, I am looking for the **posterior probability density function** after a change of variables.

I have a MCMC where I am estimating two parameters:
$$
(\log\alpha, \log\beta)
$$

I have run the sampler and have the resulting chain representing the joint posterior of these two parameters. I would like to do a change of variables to determine the probability density functions for $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

In the previous answer they were just looking for the expectation value of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. This value is commonly given in summaries of MCMC methods as:

$$
E[f(\theta)]\approx\frac{1}{M}\sum_{t=0}^{M-1}f(\theta^{(t)}),
$$
where $\theta$ is the parameter, $f$ is the transformation function, $t$ is the element in the chain of total length $M$. Thus, to find the **expectation values** of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ you can just do $e^{\log\alpha}$ and $e^{\log\beta}$ on the chain.

Now in terms of the **pdf** of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, I believe I need to bring in the Jacobian:
$$
J=\begin{vmatrix}
e^{\log\alpha} & 0 \\
0 & e^{\log\beta}
\end{vmatrix}=\alpha\beta
$$

where I find that if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are independent then the joint pdf after a change of variables is:

$$
f(\alpha,\beta)= \frac{f(\log\alpha,\log\beta)}{J}=\frac{f(\log\alpha,\log\beta)}{\alpha\beta}.
$$

The marginal pdfs would be:
$$
f(\alpha) = \frac{1}{\alpha}\int\frac{f(\log\alpha,\log\beta)}{\beta}d\beta,\\
f(\beta) = \frac{1}{\beta}\int\frac{f(\log\alpha,\log\beta)}{\alpha}d\alpha.
$$

Is this correct? Normally to get a marginal pdf from a MCMC chain you take the histogram across one parameter. In terms of taking my chain of $\log\alpha$ and $\log\beta$ values to get a pdf for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ do I just take the weighted histogram of the chain values with a weight $\frac{1}{\alpha\beta}$.

Thanks I am a new user and am grateful for any help! (I also apologize for the notation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Jacobian formula does produce the density of the transform: when $\alpha=\Psi(\theta)$,
$$f_\alpha(\alpha)=f_\theta(\Psi^{-1}(\alpha))\left|\frac{\text d\Psi^{-1}(\alpha)}{\text d\alpha}\right|.$$ But, once the MCMC simulation is over, the Jacobian has no role to play whatsoever. Namely, if $x_1,\ldots,x_T$ is an MCMC sample from $\pi$ then $\Psi(x_1),\ldots,\Psi(x_T)$ is a sample from $\Psi_*(\pi)$, the [pushforward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure) measure. This is also why the average$$\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T h(\theta^{(t)})$$is a converging estimator of $\mathbb E[h(\theta)]$ which is [both](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) the expectation of the random variable $\alpha=h(\theta)$ and the expectation of the transform by $h$ of the random variable $\theta$.

Comment: I've never heard of measure theory before. Can you clarify when to use the Jacobian. After the MCMC is done do I just take $exp(\log(\alpha)$ to get the posterior distribution for $\alpha$?

Comment: You need the Jacobian to _express_ the density function of $\exp\{\log(\alpha)\}$ but not to create a sample of $\alpha$'s.